# codeigniter loading views into variables, extra characters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m trying to process a menu in the controller as follows:

```
/**
  * Renders the html output for the navigation items
  */
 function _render_nav_items($current, $base_url) {

  $nav_items  = '';
  foreach($this->_get_nav_items() as $nav_item) {
   $nav_items .= $this->load->view(
    'admin/nav/nav_item',
    array(
     'nav_item' => $nav_item,
     'base_url' => $base_url
    ),
    true
   );
  }

  return $nav_items;
 }
```

nav_item.php :

```
<li><a href="<?=$base_url.$nav_item['controller']?>"><?=$nav_item['name']?></a></li>
```

But I get the following output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJPGW.png

Any ideas of why that is, I’ve tried running trim and compress on the output but I can’t get those extra characters/whitespace removed from the output.

I have ignored this issue for some time but can't seem to solve it however it seems to occur wherever I have php-code in the view I load, when the php code is removed it loads fine with no extra spaces/characters.

Comment: I think this will just be whitespace or line breaks in your `nav_item.php`.  Check for any spaces at the end of each line etc

Comment: Have you viewed the plain page source code? I've found the dev tools in Chrome and Firefox add extra formatting and code.

Comment: did you notice there is a white-space in the end of your **`nav_item.php`** ?

Comment: @Pattle I removed that and it seems to have no effect. The problem seems to dissappear when the php-code is removed.